# Is it possible to run X11 on FreeBSD on a Hyper-V virtual machine?

Tags: x11, xorg, freebsd

If so, what do I need to do to make it work? Currently I'm getting a "No devices to configure. Configuration failed." error when trying to run `X -configure`.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 separate ends to an X session - the display and the client. If you've not come across this before then it can be a bit confusing - the display (where the windows get rendered and where the keyboard and mouse input comes from) is the the **server** and the programs you want to run are **clients**. It doesn't make a lot of sense to run a display on a VM unless you are trying to provision a virtual desktop. If you merely want to run X programs and interact with them, then do that: start with a preconfigured terminal - since you are using Hyper-V then you probably sit in from of MS-Windows machine - try mobaterm. SSH to your VM (you may need to tweak the settings to get X-Forwarding working - you can check by running `echo $DISPLAY` - if its null, X forwarding is not enabled) then start up a program from the command line, e.g.

```
xterm &
```

You can script this from your local machine to start a program launch menu which will then allow you to run more programs with point and click.

OTOH if you really want to provision VDI, BSD seems an unusual choice.

Comment: Why would BSD be an unusual choice?

Comment: Fantastic OS - perfect for server stuff. But limited hardware support, limited desktop software.

Comment: My company has 10 workstations for the developers with new, current, off the shelf parts running FreeBSD and no issues. We also probably use the same software everyone does; again with no issues. So I don't understand, and disagree with, the comment.

Comment: After Firefox, chromium and any terminal emulator (which I expect are available on BSD) the apps I use most on Linux are Microsoft Teams, Gimp and Audacity - none of which have official BSD ports.

Comment: I use gimp and audacity daily and have so for over a decade. Both are in ports and packages. Don't know why you think otherwise. I don't know anything about Microsoft Teams except it runs on the Linuxulator.